# my Ubuntu 18.04 gets stuck on splash screen

Tags: boot, 18.04, lts, plymouth

My computer gets stuck on the splash screen unless I immediately press <kbd>esc</kbd> and then <kbd>ctrl+alt+F2</kbd> if I don't press the second keyboard command I will get stuck in the text mode until I press it. I have no idea how to troubleshoot this my profile seems to load if I let the splash run as I have autologin enabled and my keyboard lights up meaning it ran the corsair issue software and loaded my profile, as it only does that after login into my user

If anyone would like to know my computer specs they are the following

**CPU:** AMD Ryzen 2700x

**Motherboard:** Gigabyte Arous GAMING x470

**Bios V.:** F42A

**RAM:** XPG Z1 DDR4 3000MHz (PC4 24000) 16GB (2x8GB) Gaming Memory Modules, 
Silver (AX4U300038G16-DSZ1)

**Video Card:** Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1080 Windforce OC GV-N1080WF3OC-8GD 
Graphics Cards)

**Power Supply:**   Corsair TXM Gold 550 W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-modular ATX

**DRIVES:** M.2  drives 1 Samsung EVO 970(Linux) && 1 Samsung EVO 960 (Windows)
1 SEAGATE 2TB SSHD(games and user files)
1TB SEAGATE Drive HDD (Backups)

Comment: Is this a new problem? Did the computer work before? Is this an older computer, or one with an older graphics card? Do you see the Ubuntu logo and some cycling dots?

Comment: this is a new problem, it worked on and off before I have had lots of issues with this computer the weird thing is I don't have any issues on my windows partition other than when it updates and messes everything up but that's windows. so I don't think its hardware unless my hardware is just incompatible with ubuntu. And yes I see the boot logo and everything but unless I immediately press the key combo mentioned above the computer will get stuck there and I will have to reboot

Answer (score 1):

The latest HWE kernel actually fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a number of things to check...

1. Make sure that your AMD Ryzen 2700x isn't one of the recalled CPUs. See https://www.extremetech.com/computing/254750-amd-replaces-ryzen-cpus-users-affected-rare-linux-bug for a start... (*this may not apply to your CPU*).
2. Update your BIOS to F42d. See https://www.gigabyte.com/us/Motherboard/X470-AORUS-ULTRA-GAMING-rev-10/support#support-dl-bios. Backup your important data before updating the BIOS.
3. Download the `Samsung Magician` from their web site and check the firmware in your Samsung SSDs. Go to https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/. Backup your important data before updating any firmware.
4. Run memtest on your memory. Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free memtest to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This will take many hours to complete.
5. Make sure you've got the latest Nvidia drivers for your GeForce GTX 1080. Version 430.50. See https://www.geforce.com/drivers

Comment: 1. wasn't that for the 1800x 2. Bios f42d actually has worse Linux compatibility as it crashes gnome. 3. already on latest firmware 4. I did a mem test a few days ago and everything came back fine. 5. I have the latest nvidia driver 435.21