# gnome-shell freezes and then after a minute crashes

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, lts

I have been having a lot of issues with Ubuntu such as hangs, crashes, refuses to load my account etc. I have eliminated hardware being the issue as I have checked all my hardware. Some of these issues were fixed by trying different combinations of kernel versions and bios versions. But I still have some gnome-shell crashes that I can't fix. Checking my logs reveals a lot of error messages I don't know how many of them or normal. I will attach 2 logs one from gnome-logs [google drive to log 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OOG6QUjkg-RmEFiCqaWpQyJ4JHcasuTJ) with only important events showed and another [google drive to log 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=11qb7uFeykkhhfPjy8vgVtc6UK71fttqu)from journal showing all that plus warnings

I have already said I eliminated hardware being the issue but I am including my specs here

**CPU:** AMD Ryzen 2700x

**Motherboard:** Gigabyte Arous GAMING x470

**Bios V.:** F42A

**RAM:** XPG Z1 DDR4 3000MHz (PC4 24000) 16GB (2x8GB) Gaming Memory Modules,
Silver (AX4U300038G16-DSZ1)

**Video Card:** Gigabyte GeForce GTX 1080 Windforce OC GV-N1080WF3OC-8GD
Graphics Cards)

**Power Supply:**   Corsair TXM Gold 550 W 80+ Gold Certified Semi-modular ATX

**DRIVES:** M.2  drives 1 Samsung EVO 970(Linux) && 1 Samsung EVO 960 (Windows)
1 SEAGATE 2TB SSHD(games and user files)
1TB SEAGATE Drive HDD (Backups)

here are my gnome extensions
I tried removing some extensions I'll add the word del in front of the extensions I removed.

```
ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 104
drwxrwxr-x 26 zany130 zany130 4096 Oct  8 14:38 .
drwx------  3 zany130 zany130 4096 Oct  9 10:19 ..
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 May  4 17:33 activityAppLauncher@rastersoft.com
**del drwxrwxr-x  6 zany130 zany130 4096 Oct  8 14:38 arc-menu@linxgem33.com**
**del drwxrwxr-x  8 zany130 zany130 4096 Sep  5 20:11 cast-to-tv@rafostar.github.com**
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Jan 22  2019 clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Jan 22  2019 CoverflowAltTab@palatis.blogspot.com
drwxrwxr-x  6 zany130 zany130 4096 Jul 23 18:52 cpufreq@konkor
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Aug 16 16:09 donotdisturb-button@nls1729
drwxrwxr-x  3 zany130 zany130 4096 Oct  3 19:59 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
**del drwxrwxr-x  2 zany130 zany130 4096 Jan 22  2019 drop-down-terminal@gs-**extensions.zzrough.org
**del drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Oct  3 19:58 extensions@abteil.org**
drwxrwxr-x  7 zany130 zany130 4096 Sep 10 23:49 gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Sep 17 00:33 hidetopbar@mathieu.bidon.ca
drwxrwxr-x  5 zany130 zany130 4096 May  4 16:40 no-title-bar@franglais125.gmail.com
**del drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 May 24 20:30 nvidiautil@ethanwharris**
**del drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Jan 22  2019 openweather-extension@jenslody.de**
drwxrwxr-x  5 zany130 zany130 4096 Sep 21 14:19 places-and-files-on-desktop@maestroschan.fr
**del drwxrwxr-x  3 zany130 zany130 4096 May 24 20:36 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com**
**del drwxrwxr-x  2 zany130 zany130 4096 Jan 22  2019 refresh-wifi@kgshank.net**
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 Sep  5 20:11 ShellTile@emasab.it
drwxrwxr-x  5 zany130 zany130 4096 Aug 30 14:54 sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net
**del drwxrwxr-x  3 zany130 zany130 4096 May 18 10:44 transparent-window-moving@noobsai.github.com**
drwxrwxr-x  4 zany130 zany130 4096 May  4 16:36 update-extensions@franglais125.gmail.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 zany130 zany130 4096 May  4 16:04 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
drwxrwxr-x  3 zany130 zany130 4096 May  4 16:37 windowIsReady_Remover@nunofarruca@gmail.com


 zany130  zany130-X470-AORUS-ULTRA-GAMING  ~  ls -al /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 8 root root 4096 Aug 16 18:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct  3 19:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 16 15:18 drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
**del drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 16 15:18 places-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com**
**del drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 16 16:23 pomodoro@arun.codito.in**
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:01 ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:01 ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Aug 16 15:18 user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
```

On top of the errors in the logs above, I am now getting the fail [whale error](https://askubuntu.com/q/662678/349837):

```
gnome-session-binary: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....
```

**Update**: now Ubuntu won't boot at all I just get a black screen with a mouse

**Update**: okay I got the system to boot but it's a 50/50 chance it will boot from a reboot a full shutdown and then power up seems to work but now all my chrome based browsers won't open websites, Firefox works fine though and another new issue I can't launch steam

**Update**: ok so I seemed to finally get most things under control no more secureboot related errors. I guess its been a combination of updating to the 5.3.6 kernel and reinstalling my Nvidia drivers and removing some extensions anyway, I found out the gnome-shell freeze is due to a memory leak in gnome as I checked when the freeze happened gnome would be using 5GB of ram. I am also still randomly getting stuck in the Plymouth boot logo maybe I should just uninstall it?

Comment: You've got a bad GNOME Shell extension. In fact, you probably have more than one bad extension. For testing purposes, go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and disable ALL extensions, reboot (or restart GNOME Shell), and see if things improve. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. ps: I thought that the HWE kernel fixed your problems, no?

Comment: it did for a time and then everything kept getting messed up again. That's how it has been with my computer for months I fix an issue then, a few days latter it comes back and/or another issue pops up. On top of the above issue happening this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/1178900/my-ubuntu-18-04-gets-stuck-on-splash-screen is happening again.

Comment: Sorry, we had a three day power outage here. Holy shit you've got WAY too many GNOME Shell extensions. As I said in my first comment, one OR MORE are giving you your problems. You also have extensions in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions that shouldn't be there... all by the same author. Etc. gsconnect has file/dev problems.

Comment: @heynnema that means shell extensions actually run in the same VM and thread as the gnome-shell?

Comment: I'm not sure where the VM came from, but yes, GNOME Shell extensions extend or modify the behavior of the GNOME Shell, and as such, can cause lots of problems if they're not written correctly. I guarantee that you're directly effected by this.

Comment: Have you disabled ALL of your GNOME Shell extensions yet?

Comment: status please...

Comment: I disabled some extensions and then it worked for a while disabled some more again worked for a while but eventually broke. Switched to KDE Manjaro. Everything is a little more stable and I am able to do way more extensions and tweaks in kde. GNOME isn't apperatly good for that, its meant to be kept at defualt. Plymouth also broke for me again and I was unable to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Please [disable Secure Boot](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UEFI/SecureBoot/Testing?action=show&redirect=SecurityTeam%2FSecureBoot).

Should that not resolve the issue, see the solutions at [PKCS Signature error/warnings running dmesg on Ubuntu Mate 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031375/pkcs-signature-error-warnings-running-dmesg-on-ubuntu-mate-18-04) which involve removing all references to NVIDIA drivers, then re-downloading [version 367.27](https://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.27/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.27.run&lang=us&type=TITAN) and reinstalling it.

Should all else fails, LWN.NET has [patches to resolve the PKCS#7 issue](https://lwn.net/Articles/651495/).

Comment: I have never enabled secure boot on my system since I decided to switch from Windows to Linux, but that message has always appered I have ignored it, however.

Comment: I tried purging and reinstalling my Nvidia drivers like you suggested above but I don't know if I messed up somewhere but now my computer runs even worse. Now it runs in slow motion

Comment: ok was able to fix the slow-motion apparently it was because although I installed the Nvidia driver it wasn't selected probley because I installed it from a recovery terminal session. so I just opened the driver selection page and changed it from the open-source one to the Nvidia one

Comment: @Andres Ortiz How are we doing on the gnome-shell freeze?

Comment: still, haven't been able to fix it,  I'm still getting the PKCS#7 In my logs I looking into the LWN.net patches but I don't know how to apply them I also tried removing some extensions to see if that helps and something I should probably mention I am now getting the fail whale error message in gnome gnome-session-b: CRITICAL: We failed, but the fail whale is dead. Sorry....

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

**You've got WAY too many GNOME Shell extensions.** As I said in my first comment, one OR MORE are giving you your problems. You also have duplicate extensions in /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions that shouldn't be there... all by the same author.

The way to troubleshoot this is to **temporarily disable ALL extensions** at https://extensions.gnome.org/local/, and remove the dups at /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions, and run for a few days and see if things stabilize.

After determining a base line, enable one extension at a time, and test some more. Any problems that arise may be due to the last extension that you enabled.

Reduce the total number of GNOME Shell extensions. You really don't need/want them all.

Last thought... if you've overclocked your CPU or RAM, disable that.